# Searching number using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to code for finding a number using typescript and javascript, which is in the list provided by the user. I want to print whether the number is in the list using button 'search'. Five input text boxes and one search text box and button for search. If the number is listed in any of the user input text boxes >> print as "Yes, the number is in the list  or mention the box(max five Boxes)" if not "Sorry, The number you are searching is not in the list"

```html
<html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
                
          Enter a Number : <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1"  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'textbox2')" maxlength="2" /><br><br>
          Enter a Number : <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2"  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'textbox3')" maxlength="2" /><br><br>
          Enter a Number : <input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3"  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'textbox4')" maxlength="2" /><br><br>
          Enter a Number : <input type="text" name="textbox4" id="textbox4"  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'textbox5')" maxlength="2" /><br><br>
          Enter a Number : <input type="text" name="textbox5" id="textbox5"  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'textbox6')" maxlength="2"/><br><br>

         <input type="text" name="textbox6" id="textbox6"/>
         <button onclick="myFunction()" value="answer">search</button>
         <script>
function movetoNext(current, nextFieldID) {
if (current.value.length >= current.maxLength) {
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
}
         </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're asking about searching number in your inputs and your question header is saying about factorials. what is your actual problem.???

Comment: you want to create form in html page right ?

Comment: Do you even know how to create an input and button ? This is some really basic stuff you are asking. Please try something and come back when you have a decent question

Comment: @RobG I can't get where OP had stated about factorial in his question body.?

Answer (score -2):

Try the below html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="myform" >
  First number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="1" value="211">
  <br>
  Last number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="2" value="1223">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search()">
</form> 

<script>
 function search(val){
       var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements.length;
       console.log(x);
      var val = ['112','1213','1234','121','142']
      // we need check the form value exist in array or not 
  }
<script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it help OP's problem ?

Comment: OP had not stated his actual requirement then how can you determine this as correct answer? OP's question itself is still unclear. So, Either you should flag it as unclear or get clear idea about question then post your answer.

Comment: OP's is very beginner to this. I hope the above example is help to give a kick start in html.